# Writing updates to xml file with XQuery and BaseX

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-update, xquery-3.0

I have a file.xml storing protocols whose structure is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<economato> 
  <protocollo>
    <numero>1</numero>
    <data>2014-12-15</data>
    <oggetto>Trasmissione prospetti di rendiconto chiusura esercizio 2012 - beni mobili proprietà dello stato</oggetto>
    <destinatario>Ragioneria Provinciale Como</destinatario>
    <operatore>MAESTRI</operatore>
    <valido>true</valido>
  </protocollo>
  ...
</economato>
```

and I would need to change/update the value of the tag "valido", for example from 'true' to 'false' of the protocollo number 1 and I would like this update to be written into the file. As I am using BaseX, following the documentation I have tried to write this query:

```
xquery let $update := doc('C:\Users\Lorenzo Enzino  Vinci\Desktop\ECONOMATO\databases\2014.xml')//economato/protocollo[numero = 1] return replace value of node $update/valido with 'false' into doc('C:\Users\Lorenzo Enzino Vinci\Desktop\ECONOMATO\databases\2014.xml')//economato
```

but I get an error like

```
[XPST0003] Unexpected end of query: 'into doc('C:\Users\Lorenzo Enzino Vinci\Desktop\ECONOMATO\databases\2014.xml')//economato'
```

So my query is wrong but I do not know where. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails, because it is invalid XQuery Update syntax. There is not `replace ... with ... into ...` command, there only is `replace ... with ...`, as the error message already indicates. It would also be unlogical, because `$update` already holds a reference to the correct xml fragment.

So you simply have to use the following XQuery:

```
let $update := doc('C:\Users\Lorenzo Enzino  Vinci\Desktop\ECONOMATO\databases\2014.xml')//economato/protocollo[numero = 1]
return replace value of node $update/valido with 'false'
```

Also, please note that updates are not automatically written back to files in the file system (to avoid accidentally overwriting files), e.g. by starting it with `basex -u`. This is explained in detail in the [BaseX wiki](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Original_Files)

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clearer. Another question please: I am supposed to send this query via BaseXClient.java in my Java application. How can I activate "-u option" from java code?

Comment: Correct, as it is explained in the wiki section I linked to.